# Having default Rails generators call a custom generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

To be clear, here's NOT what I'm trying to:

- Have my custom generator call a default Rails generator
- Replace a default Rails generator with my own

What I want to do is have my generator be invoked automatically when I call:

```
rails generate scaffold User name age:integer
```

I'm not writing a test replacement or anything, it's completely custom. All information I find about generators out there involve one of those first two cases but not what I want to do. As soon as I found `hook_for` I immediately thought that was exactly what I needed, but it appears to do the opposite -- invokes another Rails generator from inside of my custom one (if I wanted a test file created for my custom generator I'd call `hook_for :test_framework` and then define a `TestUnit::MyCustomGenerator` class somewhere).

I suppose I could monkey patch the default scaffold generator to call mine but that feels dirty. I've looked into some gems that do something similar like https://github.com/Skalar/i18n-yaml-generator but trying to convert that to use an initializer and `lib/generators` isn't working for me. The scaffold_generator runs but mine never gets called.

Comment: No, I ended up creating a new custom generator that would call Rails's default and then mine. For example `rails g localized_scaffold User name` first invokes `scaffold User name` and then runs through my own localization generation code.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works from lib/generators/

```
$ rails g generator scaffold
      create  lib/generators/scaffold
      create  lib/generators/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb
      create  lib/generators/scaffold/USAGE
      create  lib/generators/scaffold/templates
$ rails g scaffold
Usage:
  rails generate scaffold NAME [options]
....
        what/will/it/create
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#generators-lookup

another way may be :)

- fork railties gem
- override Rails::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator class to your liking
- install locally or specify source path in Gemfile

also if 'its completely custom', it is just fair to call it a different name, no?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement to yours, I want to invoke the pundit generator from the scaffold generator automaticaly.

Seperate to this I have also set up various generator templates in a dedicated gem. To have the Rail Scaffold generator invoke the pundit policy generator, I added a line to my gem's railtie.rb:

```
module MyGenerator
  class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
    config.app_generators do |g|
      g.templates.unshift File::expand_path('../../templates', __FILE__)
    end

    Rails::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator.hook_for :pundit, as: :policy, type: :boolean
  end
end
```